# Pfaffian form meaning

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

What does Pfaffian form mean? I can't find it anywhere. Is it just a 1 form on a manifold $M$?

Comment: Where did you see this written?

Comment: Libermann, Symplectic Geometry and Analytical Mechanics.

Comment: Yes, this is a classical term for $1$-forms.

Comment: Ok thank you. How the hell there are so many names for the same object!

Comment: Anosov, in his book Geodesic Flows On Closed Riemannian Manifolds With Negative Curvature (published in 1969), also uses the phrase "Pfaffian form" to mean a differential $1$ form.